# rankNet in cellchat, different in and out of a loop

Tags: r

I have a problem that I cannot explain. This is my code:

```
cellchatlist.sources <- cellchatlist[2]
cellchatlist.targets <- cellchatlist[c(1, 3:8)]
measure <- c("weight", "count")
combined_graphs.comp <- list()
for (i in seq_along(cellchatlist.sources)) {
  for (j in seq_along(cellchatlist.targets)) {
    for (k in seq_along(measure)) {
    
    graph <- rankNet(
      cellchat, mode = "comparison", stacked = F, do.stat = TRUE,  return.data = F, 
      color.use = c("#2166ac", "#b2182b"), measure = measure[k], do.flip=T,
      sources.use = as.character(cellchatlist.sources[i]),
      targets.use = as.character(cellchatlist.targets[j]),
      title = paste0(measure[k],":",cellchatlist.sources[i], " to ", cellchatlist.targets[j])
    )
    combined_graphs.comp[[length(combined_graphs.comp) + 1]] <- graph
    }
  }
}
```

it works and produces a list of 14 graphs the end. The "weight" graphs are fine. The problem is with the "count" graphs: they have a limit of 1 on the axis! It is like the function arbitrarily sets a y axis limit of 1 when running measure = "count". However, when I run the same function, using an example pair of sources and targets (e.g. source[1] and target[2]), the graph is a sexpected, without a limit of 1 on the y axis!

```
rankNet(cellchat, mode = "comparison", stacked = F, do.stat = TRUE, sources.use = as.character(cellchatlist.sources[1]), return.data = F, measure = "weight",
        do.flip=T,  targets.use = as.character(cellchatlist.targets[2]), color.use = c("#2166ac", "#b2182b"))
```

Any suggestions?